# Perl Script to delete files in directory if file permission other than 444 (chmod 444 in unix)

Tags: perl

We need to delete some files in a particular directory  if it matches
 following criteria

1. Files should be older than 72 hours
2. If the file permission is read-only  chmod 444 in unix then you shouldn't
   delete that  file. Other files permission if it is older than 72 hours we have to
   delete the file from directory.

   Please help me with this perl script

Regards

Vikram

Answer (score 1):

Why would you write a Perl script to do this when `find` has options for it already?

You can use `find` with the `-perm` and `-mtime` options to select files matching your criteria. You'll probably also want to use `-maxdepth 0` if you don't want to descend into subdirectories.

A good start would be something along the lines of:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 ! -perm 0444 ! -mtime 2 -delete
```

although I'd test it *very* thoroughly before adding that `-delete` at the end :-)

That *should* (from memory, so test it first) delete files in the current directory with a permission other than `444` and that weren't modified in the last three days.

Comment: You probably need to escape the `!` with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using find(1) will be faster.

But if you want to do it in perl, here's a sample script which will build the list of files to delete and then zap them all in one go.

```
use strict;

my $dir = '/some/directory';

opendir DIR, $dir;
my @list =
    map { "$dir/$_" }
    grep { -f "$dir/$_" && -M _ > 3 && ((stat _)[2] & 0777) == 0444 }
    readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

unlink @list;
```

Add checks and error messages and whatnot as appropriate.  And **above all**, DON'T absent-mindedly run it on your home directory to make sure it works (as I just did, after changing the conditions slightly to make sure it matched a few files) :)